# Maximize $xy^2$ when $x + y = 8$

Tags: calculus, optimization

Problem: Maximize $(xy^2)$ when $x+y = 8$

1. I have 2 variables here and I have gotten the problem down to a one variable problem by taking $x+y=8$ and getting $y = 8 - x$.
2. I now plug (y) back into the original so the original now looks like $(x)*(8-x)$, which is $8x - x^2$
3. I have taken the derivative of $(8x - x^2)$ and that derivative is $(8-2x)$.
4. I set the derivative to $0$ and found that a critical point is when $x = 4$.

Okay so now all the information is out there, the main problem I am having is with the extreme values.

Looking back at the $x + y = 8$, one would think the extreme values are when $x = 8 $and $y = 0$ and when $x = 0$ and $y = 8$, which I believe is not the case.

The real extreme values are when $x = 1$ and $y = 7$ and $y = 1$ and $x = 7$, because if you were to plug a zero into ($xy^2$) for either variable then you would get $0$.

The issue I am having now is when I plug in the critical point $x = 4$ into the $(8x - x^2)$ I get back a local max of $16$, but to me that does not make sense because I have to provide 2 values $x = ??$ and $y = ??$ to show that $xy^2$ is maximized. I guess I could just show a x and re-write $xy^2$ the way I did.

Another thing that confuses me is when I plug in $(4)(4^4)$ which is $xy^2$, I got $64$ and not $16$. I know its with different variables but I think it should still work

My problems.

1. For what values of $x$ and $y$ will I maximize $xy^2 $?
2. Did I do this correctly and if not where did I go wrong and could you explain how to not do this again?

Comment: Draw out $8x -x^2$, see where the extremes are by looking.

Comment: There is a local max of 16 at x = 4.

Comment: The thing about it is x + y = 8., and you'd think x = 0 and y = 8 is extreme, but not really because that only minimizes the xy^2. Thats the point I need help with. When x = 0 the answers is 0 and when x = 8 the result is 0

Comment: Are you struggling to see because you think it’s counter intuitive? The answer as you solved, and see, is at x=y=4. You can see on the graph what happens at x =0 or 8. Maybe once you stop fixating on x+y=8 => (false deduction btw) max is at x=0 or 8

Comment: Problem has a mistake in it. Look at answer, but now I understand. Thanks pal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I now plug (y) back into the original so the original now looks like (x)*(8-x), which is 8x - x^2

The value is $xy^2$, so you should get $x(8-x)^2$

> but to me that does not make sense because I have to provide 2 values x = ?? and y = ?? to show that xy^2 is maximized.

You don't, because once you've chosen one the other is determined by the constraint $x + y = 8$. Remember, you're not finding the maximum over all values $x$ and $y$, only those values whose sum is 8.

Comment: I think I understand now.

Comment: I went ahead and distribute the x*(8-x), but If I would of kept it original of would have notice when x = 4 and y =4 that is when xy^2 is maximized.

Comment: I literally made a dumb mistake. the x(8-x)^2 mistake.